# What does it mean, "button it up"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Halsey, who is scratching the neck, met by Nimitz. Later it was declared Halsey is suffering from shingles.

> Nimitz: Guess you don't like the chokers either.
>
> Halsey: I'd get grease on that thing just trying to **button it up**.
>   Makes me look like a damn waiter.

What does it mean, "button it up"?

I find this line in movie Midway 2019.

Comment: Halsey wearing a coat .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From context, it sounds like he referring to wearing a type of tie or collar ("choker"). If that is case, he literally means he would get grease on the "choker" as he buttoned it up.

Comment: Chocker would normally be a tight necklace. I am guessing in this passage he means a bow tie (waiters wear bow ties, because a normal tie might end up in the soup). Possibly it also hints that they would rather be in uniform than in a tuxedo.